# Dynamic memory allocation vs Using pointer

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

im new to the C language and im trying to understand the basic of memory allocation .
here I have two function that produce the exact same result, but only one of them using the malloc() function and the other one is not.

**FIRST FUNCTION**

```
int First()
{
    int arr[] = {11, 13, 7, 12, 16};
    int length = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
    
    // NOT using malloc
    int arr2[length];

    // Initialize elements to 0
    for (int i=0; i < length; i++)
        arr2[i] = 0;
    
    // Print results
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr2[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**SECOND FUNCTION**

```
int Second()
{
    int arr[] = {11, 13, 7, 12, 16};
    int length = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
    int *arr2;

    // Here im using malloc to allocate memory
    arr2 = malloc(sizeof *arr2 * length);

    // Initialize elements to 0
    for (int i=0; i < length; i++)
        arr2[i] = 0;
    
    // Print results
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr2[i]);

    return 1;
}
```

Both of this two functions will print: `0 0 0 0 0`.

What are the differences between this two approaches ? I know that using malloc(or memset) to allocate memory based on a variable is the right approach , but im trying to understand why exactly ?

Thanks!

Comment: `int arr2[length];` requires the compiler to support variable-length arrays, which is optional since C11 (and e.g.: not supported in MSVC)

Answer (score 3):

The difference is the *lifetime* of the objects. Basically it means when the object is valid and it can be accessed.

Generally, there are three lifetime types:

### Static

The object is valid all the time

Example:

```
int* foo(void) {
  static int A[10];
  return A;
}
```

Array `A` is always valid. It can be safely returned from a function.

### Automatic

The object is valid from its definition to end of the block where it was declared

Example:

```
void foo(void) {
  int *p;
  {
    int A[10];
    ... A is valid here ...
    p = &A[0]; // p points to 
    *p = 42; // still valid
  }
  // A is no longer valid
  *p = 666; // UB strikes, expect everything
}
```

A pointers to automatic objects should never be returned from functions because they would point to non-existing objects. Any use of value of such a pointer triggers *Undefined behavior*.

### Dynamic

The lifetime is controlled by the program. It starts with memory allocation via `malloc()` or similar functions. It ends when calling `free()` on the pointer to this object. Dynamic object can only be accessed via a pointer.

Example:

```
int* foo(void) {
  int *p;
  {
    p = malloc(sizeof(int[10])); // p points to an object for 10 ints
    *p = 42; // still valid
  }
  *p = 43; // still valid
  return p; // still valid though function has returned
}

int *p = foo();
*p = 44;
free(p); // release 
*p = 666; // UB strikes, expect everything
```

Forgetting to call `free()` usually leads to the memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

The second function has a memory leak because the dynamically allocated array was not freed.

The first function is conditionally supported by compilers due to using a variable length array. Also if the size of the array is big then it can occur such a way that the array will not be allocated.

And the function `memset` allocates nothing.

Answer (score 0):

One of the differences that I can come up with is the sizes of the arrays.
In your first function, if you put `sizeof(arr2)` at the end, you will get 20. But at your second function, when you put `sizeof(arr2)` you will get 8. (Size of a pointer depends on your computer. A pointer's size is 8 bytes in 64-bit mode. And 4 bytes in 32-bit mode.)